# Showing function is lebesgue integrable

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I have a function $f(x) = \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{1+(\log(x))^2}$ and I am trying to find whether this is Lebesgue integrable on $[1,\infty)$.

I'm really not sure where to start on this one. It seems like it perhaps should be lebesgue integrable because both $\sin(1/x)$ and $1+\log(x)^2$ are going to zero, but I know this is no guarantee.

Any general tips on showing whether a certain function is lebesgue integrable or not is also mush appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $1 \leqslant x$, we have

$$0 < \sin \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{x}.$$

In fact, $\sin \frac{1}{x} \sim \frac{1}{x}$ as $x\to \infty$, so the question is whether

$$\frac{1}{x(1+(\log x)^2)}$$

is integrable.

Comment: And that is integrable by noting that it is less than $\frac{1}{x(log(x))^2)}$ and then the substitution $u=log(x)$?

Comment: Exactly. If you have a complicated function $f$, you often can easily determine whether it's integrable by looking for an integrable majorant or a non-integrable minorant of $\lvert f\rvert$ that is simpler. Of course it's not always easy. But quite often combinations of powers of $x$ and logarithms work.

Comment: Okay great. I actually meant to also ask about the region $(0,1)$ and whether it was integrable there. Do you have any hints for this? Thanks

Comment: $\lvert\sin \frac{1}{x}\rvert \leqslant 1$, and $1+(\log x)^2 \geqslant 1$. And the function is continuous.

Comment: Ah yes of course, thank you. I was thinking that there was an issue with $log(x)$ at the origin, but of course $\frac{1}{1+(logs)^2}$ is tending to zero.